# Split XML file into multiple files based on a unique element value

Tags: xslt

I have some XML, which I need to split it into several XML based on the value of the title. I need to group and combine into one XML if title has the same value
that the input is.

I need to split the following XML file

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1224-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2009</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2010</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1224-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2012</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title> ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2013</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2013</DueDate>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1224-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1224-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2011</DueDate>
  </Item>

</Items>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
<Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
<Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
<Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
<Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>
<Item>
    <Title>ABCD-1234-THND</Title>
    <DueDate>01-02-2008</DueDate>
  </Item>
  <Item>

</Items>
```

Comment: Is an xslt 2.0 solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming xslt 2 is available, you can use `result-document` to specify the output location.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Items">
        <!-- Group Items by Title -->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Item" group-by="Title">
            <!-- Write each group to a file with the title in the name -->
            <xsl:result-document href="items-{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
                <Items>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </Items>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: you can use result-document to specify the output location...can you help me with an example?

Comment: Are you having trouble running the example in the answer?